# Is there any book about fundamental FEM theory using similar terminology as Comsol MultiPhysics?

Tags: finite-element, comsol

I am considering  to solve complexed PDE systems, like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638845/the-solution-of-a-set-of-equations-is-about-to-appear-but-still-elusive), using Comsol MultiPhysics. The PDEs are different from the General Form provided by Comsol. The Weak Form module may be worth a shot.

But I am no export in FEM theory. Even if I become one after learning, there might be a distance from FEM theory to Comsol weak form implementation, say different terminology.

So, I was wondering if there are some books or materials that details the fundamentals of FEM empolying terminology similiar to Comsol, maybe like this [website](https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/finite-element-method) given by Comsol but with much more details as a textbook on FEM theory.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.